# C# - How to pass null value if the Byte Array is not provided?

Tags: c#, image, sql-server-2008, parameters, .net-4.0

I am trying to pass `null` value to image database field if the `ImageByteArray` is not provided to `Parameters.Add` as shown here

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Img", SqlDbType.Image)).Value =
    DBNull.Value ? null : ImageByteArray;
```

but I am getting error that says

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DBNull' to 'bool'

first is that correct way to do it >

if yes the how to pass `null` value if the `ImageByteArray` is not provided ?

i do not know if am right what i want to do is passing null to the parameter if the Byte Array is not provided so I avoid the `Procedure or function  expects parameter '@img', which was not supplied.`

Comment: You aren't passing the value. You are trying to treat it as a boolean. You typed `someCondition ? value1 : value2`.

Comment: You're passing `DBNull.Value` to the ternary operator. That only accepts a boolean and DBNull.Value cannot be implicitly converted to a boolean.

Comment: You probably wanted to write `ImageByteArray ?? DBNull.Value` instead?

Comment: i do not know if am right what i want to do is passing null to the parameter if the Byte Array is not provided so I avoid the `Procedure or function  expects parameter '@img', which was not supplied.`

Comment: How is `ImageByteArray` declared? How is it passed in? If it's a `byte[]` can it really be null? Or just zero length?

Comment: it is declared like that  `Byte[] ImageByteArray;` and in some cases it has value and in another it not has assigned to value  the it go through alot of steps so posting code realated to it may be borging for you the idea is that i want to avoid `Procedure or function expects parameter '@img', which was not supplied` when binding parameters

Answer (score 2):

```
DBNull.Value ? null : ImageByteArray;
```

This part is wrong. Because ternary operator needs to be a boolean result to compare. Try the following one;

```
(object)ImageByteArray ?? DBNull.Value;
```

If ImageByteArray is null it will assign DBNull.Value to your sql parameter.

Comment: thanks but I got `error cannot be applied to operands of type 'byte[]' and 'System.DBNull'` and when I removed one `?` sing i got missing `:`

Comment: IIRC for this to work, `ImageByteArray` has to be nullable, i.e. `byte?[]`

Comment: @sam can you share your full code? because byte[] is a nullable type and it shouldn't be cause any error. Maybe you might missing something?

Comment: `byte[]` is an array, an array is a reference type and therefore nullable.

Comment: it is declared like that  `Byte[] ImageByteArray;` and in some cases it has value and in another it not has assigned to value  the it go through alot of steps so posting code realated to it may be borging for you the idea is that i want to avoid `Procedure or function expects parameter '@img', which was not supplied` when binding parameters

Comment: @sam can you just put (object) before ImageByteArray for now? I will dig in and will reply with a more proper reply

Comment: @sam it's cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Img", SqlDbType.Image)).Value = (object)ImageByteArray ?? DBNull.Value right ?

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I'm using:

```
command.Parameters.Add("@Img", SqlDbType.VarBinary, ImageByteArray == null ? -1 : 
ImageByteArray.Length).Value = ImageByteArray ?? (object)DBNull.Value;
```

Basically, when you send your byte array to your database, you need to specify if it is empty or not. Sending -1 for the length means the received array will be empty.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience